# Populating 2 tables from one controller in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

Just looking for confirmation on what the best way to write a row to 2 separate tables is in an MVC framework (specifically Laravel 5.1)

I have a sign up form, which should eventually add a row to my "users" table and my "profiles" table (These tables have a 1 to 1 relationship).

So, by default my AuthController calls my User models "create" function. Is it OK to have the same function also call my Profile model? Something in the long lost "1st year at uni" part of my brain says this shouldn't happen.

Sorry, I don't have access to my actual code at the moment, but this is basically what I'm getting at:

```php
AuthController
{
    function create($data)
    {
        User::create([
            $data STUFF GOING TO PLACES    
        ])

        Profile::create([
            $data STUFF GOING TO PLACES    
        ])
    }
}
```

EDIT: To clarify, when a user registers for the site, they will create a row in the users table AND the profile table. So each user row will always have 1 corresponding profile row.

Comment: There's nothing wrong 'per se' with what you're doing here. Does your use have a profile? If that's the case, it would make more sense for the user model to take care of the profile, since I assume that `a user has a profile - oneToOne` and a profile belongs to a user. Do you see where I'm going with this? It would make more sense for the User Model to populate the profile table, since they're in a relationship.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're getting at. I agree that since they "1 user has 1 profile", both tables could easily be edited by the same model. I just thought the standard was to have one model for each table.

Comment: Again, you're not wrong, and there's nothing wrong with what you're doing. But the way laravel likes to handle things it makes more sense, in laravel context, to do what I suggested. Programmatic, both make equal sense.